# Redirect all https visitors to http with exception of one URL

Tags: .htaccess

I would like to redirect anybody arriving at my site on HTTPS back to the HTTP version with a 301 redirect.

So:

https://www.domain.com to http://www.domain.com
https://www.domain.com/contact to http://www.domain.com/contact

But I would like to allow one URL to remain on https

So:

https://www.domain.com/secure/secureFile.php should continue to be served over HTTPS with no redirections

How can I achieve this within my .htaccess file?

Thank you :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule !^secure/secureFile\.php http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^secure/secureFile\.php https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC,R=301]
```